# SSLv3 support in Chrome 40+

Tags: google-chrome, ssl, openssl

One 1 machine I am using openssl 1.0.0m with only support for SSLv3 ciphers. I am also using Chrome 47 that uses this openssl server successfully. I am not setting SSLv3-fallback.

On another machine with the same setup Chrome sporadically displays (only in Chrome 46+, not IE/Firefox):

ERR_SSL_FALLBACK_BEYOND_MINIMUM_VERSION

ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

This happens even if SSLVersionFallbackMin=tls1 is used as a command line flag to start Chrome.

"An update on SSLv3 in Chrome."
https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/security-dev/Vnhy9aKM_l4

> SSLv3-fallback is only needed to support buggy HTTPS servers. Servers 
>   that correctly support only SSLv3 will continue to work (for now) but 
>   some buggy servers may stop working.

How is it possible to determine specifically what the issue is with the "buggy" HTTPS server without updating the ciphers to TLS 1.2?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/), [Web Apps Stack Exchange](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/) or [Webmaster Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: This is about development as it relates to interacting with a buggy https server.